# Programming STM32 with Arduino IDE using raspberry pi 4 type B

Tags: raspberry-pi-os

i'm use
https://github.com/stm32duino/BoardManagerFiles/raw/main/package_stmicroelectronics_index.json
for downloaded STM32 board in Arduino IDE using raspberry pi, but i got command "tool STM32Tools is not available for your operating system"
[image]

my question is, can I program STM32 using raspberry pi 4 type B. thank you

Comment: See [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) to see how this site works
and [How do I ask a good question?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You can install the Arduino IDE on a Raspberry Pi running RaspiOS. I'm just not sure that the Arduino IDE is the best way to program STM32 devices. This is more of a Linux question than a Raspberry PI question.